# How can I prevent re-rendering when updating a state from a different component?

Tags: reactjs

Im building a react table, which shows rows for every person, and who he voted for.

This is my index.js:

```
function Tables() {
  const { columns, rows } = votersTable();

  return (
          <DataTable
            table={{ columns, rows }}
            isSorted={false}
            entriesPerPage={true}
            showTotalEntries={true}
            noEndBorder
            canSearch={true}
          />
  );
}
```

When updating (via  a button) who the perosn voted for, in votersTable() as follows:

```
const handlePresidentChange = (event, newPresident, rowId, pid) => {
    // Update the selected value for the specific row

    const updatedPersonData = {
      speculation: newPresident,
      // Add other updated fields here
    };

    updatePerson(pid, updatedPersonData)
      .then(() => {
        // Create a copy of the current electorsList
        const updatedList = [...electorsList];

        // Find the index of the object with the same id in the copied array
        const indexToUpdate = updatedList.findIndex((person) => person.id === pid);

        // If a matching object is found, update its president property
        if (indexToUpdate !== -1) {
          updatedList[indexToUpdate].president = newPresident;

          // Update the state with the new array
          setElectorsList(updatedList);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error updating data in Firestore:", error);
      });

    //Should send a write command to firestore
  };
```

The whole DataTable components gets re-rendered again.

How can I prevent that?

I tried disabling setElectorsList(updatedList), it doesnt cause a re-render, but this doesnt update the line. Only after a refresh and when the web extracts the data from firestore, I see the correct updated value.

Comment: is this button inside of the table component?

Comment: @Maziarparsi its inside votersTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,lets talk a little  about re-rendering process in react.
a component, will always re-renders if any state in parent component changes,or if component's own Props changes.
when props change, the component will re-renders to make sure everything is updated.

in your example,as you said, columns and rows change when we use voterTable button. they are props in DataTable, so they make DataTable to re-renders. when props changes, re-render is inevitable.